# Как обратиться к глобальной временной таблице из другого сеанса?

Tags: sql-server

Глобальные временные таблицы видны во всех сеансах. **Глобальные временные таблицы автоматически удаляются при завершении сеанса**, создавшего таблицу, и прекращении обращения к ним всех прочих задач. Каким образом можно воспользоваться глобальной временной таблицей из другого сеанса? Например, в одной хранимой процедуре создалась глобальная временная таблица и поместились данные в эту таблицу, а из других процедур идёт обращение к глобальной временной таблице

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test2
AS
    CREATE TABLE ##t(Test1Col  int);
    INSERT INTO ##t VALUES (2);

GO
```

Обращаемся к глобальной временной таблице из другой процедуры:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test1
AS
    SELECT Test1Col FROM ##t;

GO
```

Возможно ли это вообще? Если нет, то есть ли какие-нибудь другие решения? Или, может быть, возможно сделать так, чтобы таблица не удалялась при завершении сеанса?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Глобальные временные таблицы автоматически удаляются при завершении
>   сеанса, создавшего таблицу, и прекращении обращения к ним всех прочих
>   задач.

Всё верно. Если `##` таблица создаётся в одной сессии, и доступ к ней осуществляется из других сессий, то в них она доступна, пока первая сессия не закрылась или к `##` таблице *есть обращение* из этих других сессий. Причём важно, есть ли обращения именно *в данный момент* времени, а не будут ли они когда-нибудь потом.

Как это действует можно видеть на следующем примере. Создадим одновременно две сессии.

**Сессия 1**

Выполним в ней:

```
CREATE TABLE ##t (Test1Col int);
INSERT INTO ##t VALUES (2);
```

и оставим эту сессию пока открытой.

**Сессия 2**

Здесь выполним:

```
SELECT * FROM ##t
```

Получим данные, которыми мы заполнили таблицу в Сессии 1, как и полагается. Теперь в Сессии 2 выполним:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM ##t
```

это вызовет блокировку `##t` (то самое "есть обращение").

Сессию 1 теперь закроем, а в Сессии 2 выполним:

```
SELECT * FROM ##t -- ok
COMMIT TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM ##t -- error
```

Хотя Сессия 1, в которой была создана `##` таблица уже закрыта, первая выборка пройдёт успешно, т.к. `##t` была нами захвачена в Сессии 2. После завершения транзакции (`COMMIT`) в Сессии 2 произойдёт освобождение `##t`, а т.к. её сессия-инициатор уже закрыта, то `##t` тут же будет удалена. Соответственно, вторая выборка завершится уже с ошибкой.

> Каким образом можно воспользоваться глобальной временной таблицей из
>   другого сеанса?

Так как вы и делаете это, но, как видно из примера выше, есть некоторые нюансы, касающиеся жизненного цикла `##` таблиц.

В зависимости от ситуации, возможны следующие варианты:

- Удерживать сессию, создавшую `##` таблицу, открытой на время доступа
  к ней из других сессий. Это, наверное, наиболее простой и наименее
  проблемный вариант, если, конечно, архитектура приложения позволяет
  его использовать.
- Можно создать `##` таблицу в одной сессии, затем в другой сессии
  произвести её захват, установив приемлемую блокировку, после чего
  сессия, создавшая `##` таблицу, может быть закрыта.
- В некоторых случаях логика приложения может позволять делать проверку
  существования/создание/заполнение `##` таблицы в каждой сессии, где
  это необходимо. В этом случае инициирующий код можно вынести в
  отдельную процедуру и исполнять по-необходимости в каждой такой
  сессии.
- Если перечисленные выше варианты не подходят, то это может быть
  знаком того, что с помощью `##` таблиц вы пытаетесь решить задачу,
  которую на самом деле следует решать, используя постоянные таблицы.
- Существует также некоторая альтернатива между `##` и постоянными
  таблицами - это создание постоянных таблиц в `tempdb` (они будут
  существовать до следующего рестарта SqlServer). Однако лично мне
  такой способ кажется "грязным".