# Как получить доступ к глобальной временной таблице в процедуре, отличной от той в которой она была создана?

Tags: sql-server

Необходимо создать временную таблицу и поместить данные из одной процедуры, а пользоваться ей в других процедурах. Как это сделать?

Если воспользоваться глобальной временной таблицей, то как получить к ней доступ из другой процедуры?

Например так:

```
-- Script my procedure.....  

select * from ##MyGlobalTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Быть может вам подойдет вот такой вариант:

```
create procedure Proc1
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    create table #SomeTable (ID int);

    exec Proc2;

    select * from #SomeTable;

end
GO

create procedure Proc2
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    if object_id('tempdb..#SomeTable') is NULL
    begin
        raiserror('Create #SomeTable first', 16, 1);
        return;
    end

    insert into #SomeTable (ID)
    values (1), (2), (3);

end
GO
```

Т.е. вместо глобальной временной таблицы использовать обычную временную таблицу, но создавать её на вызывающей стороне.

Для удобства в Proc2 где-то в начале можно добавить комментарий, описывающий временные таблицы, ожидаемые процедурой. На время отладки строку кода `create table #` можно разкомментировать, тогда IntelliSense будет видеть таблицу далее по коду, потом не забыть закомментировать обратно. Альтернативно можно по условию, которое никогда не выполнится (напр. `if 1 = 0`) написать тот же самый `create table #`, этого будет достаточно, чтобы IntelliSense её видел, хотя по факту внутри Proc2 таблица никогда создана не будет:

```
create procedure Proc2
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    --Expected tables:
    --следующую строчку разкомментировать на время отладки
    --create table #SomeTable (ID int);

    -- Либо
    if (1 = 0)
        create table #SomeTable (ID int);

    ...
end
GO
```

Comment: А по глобальным таблицам недавно был вопрос ([вот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/501285/193999)).

Comment: хороший пример. Проблема, что IntelliSense не видит таблицу #SomeTable в процедуре Proc2, хотя Select выполняется. Хотя это понятно, на тот момент её ещё нет.

Comment: Подскажите Как сделать так чтобы IntelliSense видел #SomeTable в процедуре Proc2 ??? , код процедуры очень большой не удобно так.

Comment: @VladimirTsybin, дополнил ответ

Comment: Именно так уже и сделал)) спасибо.